# Execute Stored Process with pass in SQL query from another table?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Currently my development environment is using SQL server express 2008 r2 and VS2010 for my project development.

My question is like this by providing a scenario:

Development goal:

I develop window services something like data mining or data warehousing using .net C#.
That meant I have a two or more database involved.

my senario is like this:

I have a database with a table call SQL_Stored inside provided with a coloum name QueryToExec.

I first idea that get on my mind is written a stored procedure and i tried to came out a stored procedure name Extract_Sources with two parameter passed in thats ID and TableName.

My first step is to select out the sql need to be execute from table SQL_Stored. I tried to get the SQL by using a simple select statement such as:

`Select Download_Sql As Query From SQL_Stored 
Where ID=@ID AND TableName=@TableName`

Is that possible to get the result or is there another way to do so?

My Second step is to excecute the Sql that i get from SQL_Stored Table.Is possible to 
to execute the query that select on the following process of this particular stored proc?
Need to create a variable to store the sql ?

Thank you,Appreciate for you all help.Please don't hesitate to voice out my error or mistake because I can learn from it. Thank you.

PS_1:I am sorry for my poor English.

PS_2:I am new to stored procedure.

LiangCk

Comment: Hint: You are "re-inventing the wheel". Data-Mining tools already exist.

Comment: i know there is alot data-mining tools exist it the word. it need to be done by requirement from out client, that they specified a window services that can be done with vs2010 and sqlserver platform.No other third parties invloved.

Comment: SQLServer + Data Mining = SQL Analysis Services.

Comment: If you're new to stored procedures I wouldn't recommend you to use analysis services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @download_sql VARCHAR(MAX)
Select
    @download_sql = Download_Sql
From
    SQL_Stored
Where
    AreaID = @AreaID
    AND TableName = @TableName

EXEC (@download_sql)
```